# How to call function with lisp style via mappings from lua in neovim?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I'm trying to use v:lua to call functions written in lua (actually it's fennel, which compiles to lua).

Now I have a function named `lisp-style` , then I can't directly use `v:lua.lisp-style()` because it's not a valid symbol in vim script.

Here's the specific situation:

```lua
_G["lisp-style"] = function() return "b" end
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>a", "v:lua.lisp-style()", {noremap=true, expr=true})
```

So, is there a better approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example,

```
function! LuaCall(...) abort
    return luaeval('_G[_A[1]](unpack(_A, 2))', a:000)
endfunction

:echo LuaCall('lisp-style', 1, 2, 3)
```

But probably you should just create another variable with a more appropriate name:

```
:lua lisp_style = _G['lisp-style']
:echo v:lua.lisp_style()
```